# Lighttpd mod_auth authentication difficulties on Safari (iPad and iPhone)

Tags: lighttpd, ipad, safari, mod-auth

I've set up lighttpd on my embedded device and configured the modules in the `lighttpd.conf`
When accessing the web pages from Chrome or Firefox from the PC I get asked for the username and password and after I supplied them the page loads.

When I do the same on the iPad or iPhone Browser I also get the authentication dialog but for some reason it pops up repeatedly.

Using the `mod_accesslog` module i was able to see, that the iPad still makes requests without using the authentication which results in `HTTP 401` for some request:

```
192.168.2.33 192.168.2.247 wwwX [10/Apr/2011:16:01:30 +0200] "GET /[...] HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://192.168.2.247/" ...
192.168.2.33 192.168.2.247 wwwX [10/Apr/2011:16:01:30 +0200] "GET /[...] HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://192.168.2.247/" ...
192.168.2.33 192.168.2.247 - [10/Apr/2011:16:01:33 +0200] "GET /[...] HTTP/1.1" 401 351 "http://192.168.2.247/" ...
192.168.2.33 192.168.2.247 - [10/Apr/2011:16:01:56 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 351 "-" ...
```

I also tried to add the `mod_access` module but that did not change anything.

Does the problem lie in the browser or the `lighttpd` webserver or its modules/configuration? How can it be fixed?

The relevant parts of my `lighttpd.conf` file look like this:

```
# mod_auth must be loaded before mod_fastcgi
server.modules = (
    "mod_auth",
    "mod_cgi",
    "mod_fastcgi"   
)
```

The section with the mod_auth configuration looks like this:

```
auth.debug = 0
auth.backend = "plain"
auth.backend.plain.userfile = "/tmp/lighttpd-plain.user"
auth.require = (
    "/" =>
    (
        "method" => "digest",
        "realm" => "myRealm",
        "require" => "valid-user"
    )
)
```

**edit:**

One thing that I forgot to mention was that the Web page makes AJAX requests using jQuery. The requests don't set the `username` and `password` variables. On all browsers this works without problems after the user has authenticated himself via the browsers popup dialog.

I think the AJAX requests on Safari might be the ones that don't use any credentials and thus get the 401 etc. Is there a way to make it use the the credentials the user provided in the dialog box?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, I have not found a general workaround. Making the cgi script that my Ajax calls used accessible without credentials worked for my specific case though.

Answer (score -1):

```
auth.require = (
    "/" =>
    (
        "method" => "digest",
        "realm" => "myRealm",
        "require" => "valid-user"
    )
)
```

That's because you're using digest authentication which is not supported / buggy on some browsers. You should either use basic method (which is not secure) or implement your own authentication using cookies. If you're interested in a secure and efficient authentication solution (build-in protection againts brute-force attacks and account sharing) please check our site: [finesec.com](http://www.finesec.com)

Comment: Is it still insecure over https?

Comment: If you use https on every page then it's secure. There're still some problems with efficieny, because with basic/digest authentication username/password is verified on each request (for every html page, css file, image, etc).

Comment: Also there's no way to logout when basic/digest authentication is used (you need to close the browser in order to logout).

Comment: Please add a comment if you're voting down.